# Video Recording stopped because battery was low, restore file?

Tags: video, nexus-4, data-recovery, video-recording

I just recoreded a Video, and my Android powered down while recording because the battery was completly empty.

Now i have a 1,5 GB mp4.tmp file that i cant open with VLC.

I have a Nexus 4 with Android 4.2.2

Is there anyway I can save this file?

Answer (score 1):

I found this - 
i had a similar problem with a mp4 file that was corrupt, and not being able to find version 1.5 of grau anymore. i came up with this solution.

> [Scenario] video.mp4 (200mb) grau version 1.6 + (only does 50% of
>   video for free version)
>
> [Directions] make 2 of the same video files and name them 1.mp4 and
>   2.mp4 this means you will copy video.mp4 in the same fold twice so you have two of them!
>
> in DOS (Run: cmd.exe)
>
> locate to the folder where you have the two video files type in the
>   command to merge the files together
>
> copy /b 1.mp4+2.mp4
>
> you will now see that 1.mp4 will be 400mb and not 200mb
>
> now use grau video repair tool and it will do 50% of the file you
>   merge. meaning you will get 100% video freee!

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=18974312#post18974312)

Answer (score 0):

MP4 video repair from Iwo Banas.

Automatically finds broken files in your droid, and using another video file from the same device as a reference, fixes it. Works like a charm.

Dont forget to donate!

(:

Comment: What's your relationship with this app? Could you add a link to it?